# Constant crashing on Bedrock server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

So I was playing on my server with my friend, and suddenly by game crashed. No problem, I'll just rejoin, I thought. So I launched the PE launcher again, and entered the server. Joined in, Terrain won't load, and when I move a bit, either the game crashes again, or i fall through the void and get kicked by the server. Is there a way to fix this, or should I just go reset my character?

Comment: What versions are u using?
Your device specs?
Is your connection stable?

Comment: Also, listing any enabled behavior and resource packs *could* be helpful in diagnosing the issue.